# chrome issue with dynamically generated img tags

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-chrome

I tried for hours now to find a answer in the internet but couldn't...

I am trying something simple now... I want to through PHP or JS a img add such as: (if "hardcoded" it work without any problem)

```
echo '<img src="http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/484989_527295087321263_1815832969_s.jpg" height=125 width=130 />';
```

But in chrome it does not display when dynamically generated. I have tried to set content-length and other headers as suggested in other posts, however I haven'T got any luck... does anyone has a answer or can walk me through a solution?

More Infos:

I am simply just echoing the line... 
I tested it at chrome 24.0.1312.52 on win7 and 25.0.1364.152 on win8. 
The html is generated fine but when I go through the debugger I see on the network tab that the status and type are 'pending'

And on the resources tab I see the image with the following informations:

```
484989_527295087321263_1815832969_s.jpg
Dimensions 1 × 1
File size 67B
MIME typeimage/png
URL http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/484989_527295087321263_1815832969_s.jpg
```

I can get more information if it helps...

Thanks

Comment: its working.Please post complete code how you are using this.

Comment: I have just used the same code in google chrome.found as working fine..

Comment: I set up a example page: http://www.rugby-darmstadt.de/show_albums.php

Comment: @fditz The exmaple page you provided is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, and of some of the users having the same issues by checking chromes extensions.

Apparently there was a "tracker blocker" ([this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disconnect/jeoacafpbcihiomhlakheieifhpjdfeo)) installed in the machine I was using, more specifically in chrome. It was holding these img requests back and not allowing them to finish.
By disallowing this app everything worked as expected.

Hope it helps other users.